# multiple possible views in a viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview, view

I have a tableview with a few items. I want to get a new view when I click on one of the cells. However, I want the view to be different depending on which cell I clicked. 
For example: I have a tableview of buildings. These buildings can be Airports, factories and houses.

When I click on a cell that shows an airport, I want the next view to be different than when I click on a cell that shows a factory.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be easily solved by giving each cell a type. If you're implementing a custom cell class add it as an enumerated type (improves readability)

```
// cell header file

typedef enum {
    CellTypeAirports,
    CellTypeFactories,
    CellTypeHouses
} CellType;

@interface CustomTableCell

// ...
@property(assign) CellType type;    

@end
```

Set the type when you're instantiating (dequeueing) the cell and then in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method check the cell's type

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // ...
    if ([cell type] == CellTypeAirports) {
        // push airports vc
    } else if ([cell type] == CellTypeFactories) {
        // factories
    }
    // and so on

}
```

If you're using standard `UITableViewCell`s then you can utilize their `tag` property to store the type.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for replying so late. I have a few questions though. If I'm going to check the type or identifier of a cell before I show the next view then I also have to assign the type/identifier first. How can I do this? Also, I suppose this works, but I only have 3 different buildings now. What if I have 100? I can't do 100 if statements to check them all...And finally, I currently use the prepareforsegue to send some data to the next view, is this still possible this way?

Comment: For setting the type - you have a method that creates/dequeues cells (`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`); for the 100 buildings problem I'd suggest using a lookup table or storing the correct parameters in each cell & acquiring them on click. To send some data just get the view controller pointer from `prepareForSegue:` and set whatever variables you need.